# CompoundPI unidentified server problem

Tags: networking, camera, pi-3b+, ubuntu, raspbian-buster

I am trying to use CompoundPI (https://compoundpi.readthedocs.io/en/release-0.4/quickstart.html) with two RPIs and an ubuntu client. CompoundPI connects multiple RPIs, that each of them has a picamera, to a client which is in this case is my PC running Ubuntu and it allows a synchronized video capturing from all RPIs. I followed the docs and when I try to find the RPI from the client it find nothing although they are connected to the same server, note I can ssh to the RPIs. I tried adding the RPI manually using the RPI IP and it gives me no response from the IP. I know that people might not be familiar with compound pi but I think its a general networking problem so any help is appreciated, please let me know if you need me to add more info to the question.

Comment: Raspbian Jessie is obsolete.

Comment: Sorry I meant raspbian buster in the tags @Milliways

Comment: I cannot find at a glance on the link you have given what CompoundPI do. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Ingo CompoundPI connects multiple RPIs, that each of them has a picamera, to a client which is in this case is my PC running Ubuntu and it allows a synchronized video capturing from all RPIs.